# Erro em C++:undefined symbol: Rec::n

Tags: c++

Boa noite a todos!

Estou estudando `C++`, e deu erro no código que tentei compilar. Acredito que seja porque o exemplo é de um livro bem antigo. Já tentei alguns chutes, mas não consegui ainda resolver o problema.

Desde já agradeço!

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  membros_static_1
//
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Rec{
private:
    static int n;
public:
    Rec(){n++;}     //Construtor
    int getRec() const{return n;}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    Rec r1, r2, r3;
    
    cout << "\nNumero de objetos: " << r1.getRec();
    cout << "\nNumero de objetos: " << r2.getRec();
    cout << "\nNumero de objetos: " << r3.getRec();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa inicializar a variavel `n`, mas esse código: `static int n=0;` não ira funcionar, você precisa declarar ela de maneira externa.

Primeiro, caso você não saiba, o que é uma *variavel estatica*?

> Uma variável estática nunca é alocada em uma pilha. Eles têm espaço alocado em diferentes armazenamentos estáticos. Isso significa que, quando declaramos uma variável estática em uma classe, essa variável é compartilhada por todos os objetos dessa classe.

Para declarar a variavel estatica, utilize esse código:

```
tipoDaVariavel Classe::nomeDaVariavel = valorDesejado
```

O seu código ficaria assim:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Rec{
private:
    static int n;
public:
    Rec(){n++;}     //Construtor
    int getRec() {return n;}
};

int Rec::n = 0;//declaração da variavel

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    Rec r1, r2, r3;
    
    cout << "\nNumero de objetos: " << r1.getRec();
    cout << "\nNumero de objetos: " << r2.getRec();
    cout << "\nNumero de objetos: " << r3.getRec();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Tambem coloquei o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@Cdigodede/FirmUtilizedProcessor#main.cpp)

Caso queira dar uma olhada em uma materia que fala sobre isso clique [aqui](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/static-in-cpp/)

Comment: outra alternativa eh nao declarar `n` como uma variavel estatica, entao inicializa-la como `int n=0`.

Comment: @AnnaMaule sim, poderia, mas com o `static` da para ele contar quantos objetos foram criados :)

Answer (score 0):

Voce não inicializou o `n`, voce deve inicia com algum valor, por exemplo `int n=0;`, senão você terá um valor aleatorio da memoria ( tambem conhecido como lixo ).